# Conversion from template class

Tags: c#, templates, inheritance, interface

I have class `MyClass<T>` where `T` is some interface:

```
class MyClass<T> where T: IMyInterface
```

I wrote several classes which extend `MyClass` using some implementation of `IMyInterface`, for example:

```
class MySecondClass : MyClass<MyInterfaceImplementation>
```

Why assignement `MySecondClass` instance to variable with type `MyClass<IMyInterface>` is not allowed?

```
MyClass<IMyInterface> x = new MySecondClass()
```

When I add implicit conversion:

```
public static implicit operator MyClass<IMyInterface>(MySecondClass c) {
    return c;
}
```

it starts working.

Comment: You need to constrain the interface. `interface IMyClass<out T> where T: IMyInterface`.

Comment: @Romoku You cant use generic out constrain with classes. Interfaces only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you want, you should declare that the type parameter `T` is covariant using the `out` keyword (see  [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) on MSDN).
You would need to modify your code a little, as covariance and contravariance can only be defined on interfaces:

```
interface IMyInterface { 
}

// note that this one is an interface now
interface IMyClass<out T> where T : IMyInterface { 
}

class MyInterfaceImplementation : IMyInterface { 
}

class MySecondClass : IMyClass<MyInterfaceImplementation> { 
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        IMyClass<IMyInterface> x = new MySecondClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! I wasn't aware of that option. It greatly simplifies things!

Answer (score 1):

`MyClass<IMyInterface>` and `MySecondClass` two different classes and compiler cannot implicitly convert object of one type to another.

And even more these two classes have only `System.Object` as common base class

Comment: `MySecondClass` inherits from `MyClass<MyInterfaceImplementation>` and `MyInterfaceImplementation` implements `IMyInterface`. I can write simple implicit converter `public static implicit operator MyClass<IMyInterface>(MySecondClass c){return c;}` and it starts working.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of the nature of generic classes (templates in c++ lingo) and by design.

For example:

```
MyClass<object> o = new MyClass<string>();
```

will also fail to compile. Generic classes are no descendants from each other just because their generic types are. They really are different classes that have no relation to each other in an object oriented sense.